# parsing dictionary of objects in c# Dictionary<string,object> data

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I am passing following json in request body

```
{
  "areaId": "1",
  "cat": "2",
  "subcat": "41",
  "location": "1100",
  "sublocation": "11001",
  "briefDescription": "thissss is brief description",
  "detailedDescription": "this is detailed obj",
  "images": {
    "image1": "base64 string",
    "image2": "base64 string"
  }
}
```

and my handler looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Dictionary<string,object> data)
{
    int areaId = Int32.Parse(data["areaId"].ToString()); //this is how i am getting area from it 

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { some objects to return });
}
```

how can I extract the images from this json in a dictionary? and what will be the efficient way of doing this

Comment: Are you asking how to get the image data from the base64 string or how to access the `image1` and `image2` fields?

Comment: Why are you using a `Dictionary`? You should be binding to an object containing properties that match the data you sending

Comment: how to access the image 1 and 2 actually images can be multiple so I want to loop over them @MattJones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a JSON object, you could use a C# JSON Library, such as [JSON.Net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

You can use the 'Paste JSON as classes' functionality of Visual Studio to get the class structure:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string areaId { get; set; }
    public string cat { get; set; }
    public string subcat { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string sublocation { get; set; }
    public string briefDescription { get; set; }
    public string detailedDescription { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public string image1 { get; set; }
    public string image2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method to deserialize the json to a 'RootObject' instance

If you want to treat the images as a dictionary, the following structure should  also work with json.net:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string areaId { get; set; }
    public string cat { get; set; }
    public string subcat { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string sublocation { get; set; }
    public string briefDescription { get; set; }
    public string detailedDescription { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> images { get; set; }
}
```

Check https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Comment: How can I handle multiple images with this approach?

Comment: now I completely understand how things will work, but I have a question thy why it is necessary that we will add a new class like (RootObject) every time (for different different kind of objects),,,,,,Is there not any generic way that we simply sniff the parameters from request object and use them?

Comment: @SaimAbdullahCh, it's not necessary, that's the serialize/deserialize approach. You could also use [Linq to Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the [Linq to Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) approach, you could do as follow:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(j);
Dictionary<string, string> images = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(JProperty im in o["images"])
{
    images.Add(im.Name, (string)im.Value);
}
```

where `j` is a string containing your JSON.